# c++ type cast operator overloading and implicit conversions

Tags: c++, casting, overloading

if I'm overloading the type cast operator, I'm running into compile errors when an implicit conversion is needed and one can't be found. Consider the simple example where I have a wrapper class that contains a type (in this case a long long):

```
class my_wrapper
{
    long long state;

public:
    my_wrapper(long long _in) : state(_in) {}

    my_wrapper& operator=(const long long rhs)
    {
        state = rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    operator long long()
    {
        return state;
    }
};
```

The question now is that if I want to cast in code to something else (eg a void* ... assume that I'm on 64bit for this) the following does not work without specifying two casts:

```
my_wrapper x1 = my_wrapper(5ll);
void* i1 = (void *) x1; // Compile Error: no suitable conversion function exists
void* i1 = (void *) (long long) x1; // Works
```

vs. if I had written something like:

```
long long i1 = 5ll;
void* i2 = (void *) i1; // Works
```

Not a big deal, but just curious if its possible to specify that the "operator long long()" should be used as the default if there is no other conversion.

Comment: Don't use C style casts in C++. Ever. They can do very different things from what you expect.

Comment: Same reason you can't write `(void*)2.5`, more or less.

Comment: Why are you using `void*` in C++? :/ Got some C library to work with? Can't you pass `&x1` instead?

Answer (score 1):

[over.match.conv]/(1.1):

> The conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are considered.
>   Those non-explicit conversion functions that are not hidden within `S`
>   and yield type `T` **or a type that can be converted to type `T` via a
>   standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1)** are candidate functions.

There is no standard conversion sequence from an integral type to `void*`<sup>1</sup>, thus the conversion operator is not a candidate.

You can try a conversion operator template:

```
template <typename T>
operator T()
{
    return T(state);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> An integer literal with value zero is the exception.

Comment: Wouldn't that have to be `reinterpret_cast<T>(state)` (which is admittedly a pretty dangerous thing to do in a template) for the conversion to `void *` to work?

Comment: @cdhowie I *just* thought of the same. But `T(state)` suffices. (Though it has the same effect by definition)

Comment: thanks. this seems to do the trick. reinterpret_cast<T>(state) has a compile time error saying it can't convert from __int64 to __int64, whereas T(state) does not. keeping the longlong() function makes the C++ style one work.

Answer (score 1):

Since `(void *)x1` effectively gives you the address of `x1.state` 
you could simply implement a `void *` cast operator.

Like so:

```
operator void *()
{
    return &state;
}
```

The drawback of this is that you can now convert `my_wrapper` to `void *` **implicitly** as well.

Luckily, you can prevent this in **C++11** by using the `explicit` specifier:

```
explicit operator void *()
{
    return &state;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to avoid having to do this. void* is only just one case. Thanks though.

Comment: @user3799309 Why `void *` anyway?