# What does this use of the `operator` keyword mean?

Tags: c++

I found the following code on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) (I was looking up what the `explicit` keyword meant.)

```
struct A
{
    A(int) {} // converting constructor
    A(int, int) {} // converting constructor (C++11)
    operator int() const { return 0; }
};
```

On the third line of the struct definition there is the line:
`operator int() const { return 0; }`

I'm not sure what that line does. What operator is being overloaded, is it int?

I looked [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) to try and figure this out myself, but I'm still scratching my head.

Comment: In the link you posted you see `operator type (2)` and if you follow the second link you get to  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307887/c-type-cast-operator-overloading-and-implicit-conversions?s=3|2.4106

Comment: @FelixKling, not sure how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a user-defined conversion operator

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

```
struct X {
    //implicit conversion
    operator int() const { return 7; }

    // explicit conversion
    explicit operator int*() const { return nullptr; }

//   Error: array operator not allowed in conversion-type-id
//   operator int(*)[3]() const { return nullptr; }
    using arr_t = int[3];
    operator arr_t*() const { return nullptr; } // OK if done through typedef
//  operator arr_t () const; // Error: conversion to array not allowed in any case
};

int main()
{
    X x;

    int n = static_cast<int>(x);   // OK: sets n to 7
    int m = x;                     // OK: sets m to 7

    int* p = static_cast<int*>(x);  // OK: sets p to null
//  int* q = x; // Error: no implicit conversion

    int (*pa)[3] = x;  // OK
}
```